# Spring boot tests fail when ran from console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a Spring Boot application. I have tests for it.

I have the following:

```
public class UsernameAuditorAware implements AuditorAware<String> {

  @Override
  public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    if (authentication == null || !authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      return null;
    }

    return Optional.of(((MyUserPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername());
  }

}
```

Which I am loading as follows:

```
  @Bean
  AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
    return new UsernameAuditorAware();
  }
```

I have integration tests that are testing my repositories and my services.

The problem is that when I run the tests from STS, they all pass. But when I run them with **mvn test** from the console they all fail with `Auditor must not be null! Returned by: class com.utils.UsernameAuditorAware!`

What am I missing? Is there a configuration that I must do? In STS I am just runnig them with right click and run as JUnit tests.

Comment: The above is not enough to help you... Could you share us a simple reproducible code?

Comment: Show the source code for a test that is failing.

Comment: The problem is that the tests fail when ran from console and not when ran from the STS. The question, following this, is what is STS doing when running tests as JUnit tests.